# Genymotion 3.4.0 - 3.5.0 GPS feature not working on Apple M1

Tags: android, google-play-services, apple-m1, genymotion, genymotion-gps

GPS feature of Genymotion Android device on macOS is not working with a message: "Google Play services are updating."

I am having this issue since 3.4.0 released. 3.5.0 also didn't fix it. Today I installed the same application to both Genymotion 3.4.0 on Windows 10 x64 with Intel i5-1135G7 and Genymotion 3.4.0 on MacBook Pro M1 2020 with macOS Ventura 13.5.1.

Both android devices are Android 11 with Google Play services are installed with Open GApps.

On macOS, the maps of the application didn't show up stating "Google Play services are updating".

On Windows, it worked as a charm without any error.

On the logcat of android device on macOS I see the following error message while it doesn't exist in the Windows. However I don't understand the underlying problem. May be someone can understand and direct us to the right direction.

Logcat output (Couldn't paste here since stackoverflow marks it as spam):
https://pastebin.com/AXBKNrQn

This is also the logcat output of the Android device on Windows.

```
09-04 16:32:59.043  7798  7798 I DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:203115000
09-04 16:32:59.043  7798  7798 I DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 203115000
09-04 16:32:59.043  7798  7798 V DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
09-04 16:32:59.059  8465  8465 I d.process.acor: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
09-04 16:32:59.065  8182  8277 I Icing   : Usage reports ok 0, Failed Usage reports 0, indexed 0, rejected 0
09-04 16:32:59.070  8182  8277 W Icing   : No valid account for uploading user actions
09-04 16:32:59.084  8182  8277 I Icing   : Usage reports ok 0, Failed Usage reports 0, indexed 0, rejected 0
09-04 16:32:59.092  8465  8465 I d.process.acor: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
09-04 16:32:59.102  8465  8465 I ContactsPerf: VoicemailContentProvider.onCreate start
09-04 16:32:59.112  8465  8465 I ContactsPerf: VoicemailContentProvider.onCreate finish
09-04 16:32:59.119  7798  7798 I Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12451000
09-04 16:32:59.131  7798  7798 I onektr_consume: Waiting for a blocking GC ClassLinker
09-04 16:32:59.135   671   729 D CountryDetector: The first listener is added
09-04 16:32:59.136  8465  8465 I ContactsDatabaseHelper: updateUseStrictPhoneNumberComparison: US
09-04 16:32:59.142  8465  8465 D ActivityThread: Loading provider contacts;com.android.contacts: com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2
09-04 16:32:59.147  7798  7821 I onektr_consume: Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
09-04 16:32:59.158  7798  7798 I onektr_consume: WaitForGcToComplete blocked ClassLinker on ClassLinker for 26.680ms
09-04 16:32:59.158  7798  7821 I onektr_consume: Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
09-04 16:32:59.158  7798  7813 W JavaBinder: BinderProxy is being destroyed but the application did not call unlinkToDeath to unlink all of its death recipients beforehand.  Releasing leaked death recipient: com.google.android.play.core.internal.zzai
09-04 16:32:59.158  7798  7813 I BpBinder: onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients: <uncached descriptor>
09-04 16:32:59.158  7798  7821 I onektr_consume: WaitForGcToComplete blocked ProfileSaver on ClassLinker for 11.268ms
09-04 16:32:59.179  7205  7205 D BoundBrokerSvc: onBind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.service.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
09-04 16:32:59.179  7205  7205 D BoundBrokerSvc: Loading bound service for intent: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.service.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
09-04 16:32:59.179  8465  8506 D ContactsDatabaseHelper: WAL enabled for contacts2.db: true
09-04 16:32:59.228  8182  8277 W Icing   : No valid account for uploading user actions
09-04 16:32:59.229  7798  7798 I Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 233316041
09-04 16:32:59.229  7798  7798 I Google Maps Android API: Google Play services maps renderer version(legacy): 203115000
09-04 16:32:59.244  8182  8277 I Icing   : Usage reports ok 0, Failed Usage reports 0, indexed 0, rejected 0
09-04 16:32:59.263  8182  8277 I Icing   : Indexing com.google.android.gms-apps from com.google.android.gms
```